# Access cassandra nodetool API progmatically

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool, scylla

I need to provide similar utility functions such as is available through

`nodetool tablestats`

I've gone over their source code but didn't find a convenient solution to accessing it through code.

Is there a library available for this?

https://github.com/mariusae/cassandra/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeProbe.java

Answer (score 1):

The `nodetool` utility is connecting Cassandra via JMX and fetch all necessary data from corresponding beans.  You [can fetch necessary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870404/read-cassandra-matrics-using-jmx-in-java/48871512#48871512) from your program via JMX as well, but I wouldn't say that this is recommended way to do - it's better to setup some "standard" monitoring solution, like, Prometheus, connect it to Cassandra, and fetch data via it...

Comment: I want to run various nodetool utility methods like "nodetool repair" and "nodetool tablestats" which isn't a good candidate to expose through prometheous. We are indeed today using prometheus to get the various performance metrics. So regarding the utilities, do you have a good idea how to do it?

Comment: As I wrote, nodetool is using JMX - you can use it as well if you need...

Comment: do you know of any wrapper for it? Seems like a lot of work to re-implement it

Comment: I don't know existing - you can of course try to reuse Cassandra's code, but it's still a lot of work...

Comment: @AvnerBarr Any jmx client  (e.g. JConsole https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html or VisualVM https://visualvm.github.io/) allows you to call jmx beans methods

Comment: For Scylla, you can use the REST API (Swagger interface in http://localhost:10000/ui/